# Simplest way to provide a service between Docker containers

Tags: docker, interoperability

I have a Docker container to run some data processing (running RStudio). At one point it would need to run an external tool (ExtTool) which needs completely different architecture: it's a Windows-only CLI tool, but I managed to pack it into a Docker with Wine and it works. I am currently running the Docker one-shot but could also leave it running and call into it.

Are there any simple ways to call ExtTool from the main Docker that don't involve building a full-fledged web service?

- I could run the ExtTool docker with an open SSH port, `scp` the input files in, `ssh -c ExtTool` and `scp` the result file out.
- I could mount a shared folder and use that to exchange the files, and monitor the incoming file system to trigger ExtTool
- Something using `docker.sock`, `curl` and starting the ExtTool docker (or `docker exec`ing) from inside the RStudio docker?

I feel like this must be a common task and I'm not searching with the right keywords.